# code which has user guess a stored word (string) until they get it right

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at python trying to make code for the 'word guessing game', where a user must guess a stored and pre-defined word.

So far, my plan is to break down the secret_word and user_guess variables into a list of characters. Then I will use a while loop to compare each character of the user_guess to the character of secret_word until there is an exact match. If on similar list positions, there is no match, the loop shall prompt the user to guess again

```
#stores the secret word, and breaks it into a list so it can later be analyzed
secret_word="BurgerKing"
list_of_secret= list(secret_word)

#user makes a guess which also becomes list
user_guess=input("Please guess the secret word:" )
list_user_guess=list(user_guess)

#defines list items?
for i in list_user_guess:
    a=list_user_guess[i]

for i in list_of_secret:
    b=list_of_secret[i]

#comparison tool?
while a in list_user_guess != b in list_of_secret:
    user_guess=input("Please guess the secret word again:" )
    if a in list_user_guess == b in list_of_secret:
        print("Correct")
```

Unfortunately the above code does not work, as I get the unexpected EOF while parsing, any clues much appreciated?

Comment: The code above does not raise the error you mentioned. Additionally, you don't need to place every character of a word inside lists to compare them, you can simply use `word1 == word2` for that.

Comment: I don't get `unexpected EOF while parsing` - I get a TypeError. Please read and provide a [mre].

Comment: Just as a note, `while a in list_user_guess != b in list_of_secret` is syntactically valid, but it isn't doing what you may expect.  It is parsed as `while (a in list_user_guess) != (b in list_of_secret)`, where `in` is the membership test operator.  If you really want to compare the words character-by-character, you can use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to iterate over both words at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Python's for-loop iterates through the items of an iterable, not its indexes. (In other languages, it would be called a `foreach` loop.) Your error is because `list_user_guess` and `list_of_secret` are lists of strings, so each `i` in them is a string, not an index as you expected. If you replace `list_user_guess[i]` and `list_of_secret[i]` each simply with `i`, your error will go away.

Python is not as hard as you think. This does exactly the same thing as your code, but without needing to iterate through the strings:

```
secret_word = "BurgerKing"
user_guess = input("Please guess the secret word: ")

while user_guess != secret_word:
    user_guess = input("Please guess the secret word again: ")
else:
    print("Correct")
```

Comment: For reference you can use the built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to get an index-based loop like in lower level languages.  But you very rarely need to work directly with list indices in python.